# How to remove the tags from my beautiful soup result (like : Address = [a,b,c,d,r......])

Tags: python, dataframe, beautifulsoup

how I can remove the tags from my beautifulsoup result
(like : Address = [a,b,c,d,r......])

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
    #
url = 'https://www.planetware.com/tourist-attractions-/oslo-n-osl-oslo.htm'
url_get = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(url_get.content, 'html.parser')
#
address=soup.find_all('p', class_="nospc")
address
<p class="nospc">Address: Nobels gate 32, N-0268 Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Akershus Festning, 0015 Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Frederiks gate 2, 0164 Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Universitetsgata 13, Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Tøyengata 53, 0578 Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Bellevue, Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Frederiks gate 2, 0164 Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Bygdøynesveien 39, 0286 Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Kongeveien 5, 0787 Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Karl Johansgt. 11, 0154 Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Rådhuset, 0037 Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Bryggegata 9, 0120 Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Sars gate 1, 0562 Oslo</p>,
<p class="nospc">Address: Kirsten Flagstads Plass 1, 0150 Oslo</p>]
```

I want something like

```
Address = ['Nobels gate 32, N-0268 Oslo', 'Akershus Festning, 0015 Oslo' ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.It will split the address part.

```
url = 'https://www.planetware.com/tourist-attractions-/oslo-n-osl-oslo.htm'
url_get = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_get.content, 'html.parser')
#
address=soup.find_all('p', class_="nospc")
addrlist=[]
for addr in address:
    addrlist.append(addr.text.split(':')[1].strip())

print(addrlist)
```

### Output:

```
['Nobels gate 32, N-0268 Oslo', 'Akershus Festning, 0015 Oslo', 'Frederiks gate 2, 0164 Oslo', 'Universitetsgata 13, Oslo', 'Tøyengata 53, 0578 Oslo', 'Bellevue, Oslo', 'Frederiks gate 2, 0164 Oslo', 'Bygdøynesveien 39, 0286 Oslo', 'Kongeveien 5, 0787 Oslo', 'Karl Johansgt. 11, 0154 Oslo', 'Rådhuset, 0037 Oslo', 'Bryggegata 9, 0120 Oslo', 'Sars gate 1, 0562 Oslo', 'Kirsten Flagstads Plass 1, 0150 Oslo']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `text` attribute to get the content within the tags:

```py
address=[x.text for x in soup.find_all('p', class_="nospc")]
print(address)
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.text` method does it. But you can't call it on a list from `find_all`
You have to iterate through the list

```
Address_text=[]

for a in address:
    Address_text.append(a.text)


In[14]: Address_text
Out[14]: 
['Address:  Nobels gate 32, N-0268 Oslo',
 'Address:  Akershus Festning, 0015 Oslo',
 'Address:  Frederiks gate 2, 0164 Oslo',
 'Address:  Universitetsgata 13, Oslo',
 'Address:  Tøyengata 53, 0578 Oslo',
 'Address:  Bellevue, Oslo',
 'Address:  Frederiks gate 2, 0164 Oslo',
 'Address:  Bygdøynesveien 39, 0286 Oslo',
 'Address:  Kongeveien 5, 0787 Oslo',
 'Address:  Karl Johansgt. 11, 0154 Oslo',
 'Address:  Rådhuset, 0037 Oslo',
 'Address:  Bryggegata 9, 0120 Oslo',
 'Address:  Sars gate 1, 0562 Oslo',
 'Address:  Kirsten Flagstads Plass 1, 0150 Oslo']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got an answer. I didn't need the 'Address' in the output

Answer (score 0):

Try this- `find_all` function always return list, `text` to get content within the tag, `split("Address:")` is split the string and `strip()` is remove spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs=
import  requests
#
url = 'https://www.planetware.com/tourist-attractions-/oslo-n-osl-oslo.htm'
url_get = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(url_get.content, 'html.parser')
#
addressArray =soup.find_all('p', class_="nospc")

address = []
for add in addressArray:
    address.append(add.text.split("Address:")[1].strip())

print(address)
```

O/P:

```
['Nobels gate 32, N-0268 Oslo', 'Akershus Festning, 0015 Oslo', 'Frederiks gate 2, 0164 Oslo', 'Universitetsgata 13, Oslo', 'Tøyengata 53, 0578 Oslo', 'Bellevue, Oslo', 'Frederiks gate 2, 0164 Oslo', 'Bygdøynesveien 39, 0286 Oslo', 'Kongeveien 5, 0787 Oslo', 'Karl Johansgt. 11, 0154 Oslo', 'Rådhuset, 0037 Oslo', 'Bryggegata 9, 0120 Oslo', 'Sars gate 1, 0562 Oslo', 'Kirsten Flagstads Plass 1, 0150 Oslo']
```

Comment: Beautiful! your code gave me the output as list. Thank you. Do you know how i can export the list into a dataframe column , say COL1? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Or use `map`:

```
 address = list(map(lambda x: x.text.split(':  ')[1], address))
 address
```

Output:

```
['Nobels gate 32, N-0268 Oslo', 'Akershus Festning, 0015 Oslo', 'Frederiks gate 2, 0164 Oslo', 'Universitetsgata 13, Oslo', 'Tøyengata 53, 0578 Oslo', 'Bellevue, Oslo', 'Frederiks gate 2, 0164 Oslo', 'Bygdøynesveien 39, 0286 Oslo', 'Kongeveien 5, 0787 Oslo', 'Karl Johansgt. 11, 0154 Oslo', 'Rådhuset, 0037 Oslo', 'Bryggegata 9, 0120 Oslo', 'Sars gate 1, 0562 Oslo', 'Kirsten Flagstads Plass 1, 0150 Oslo']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got an answer. Your code didnt work for me. maybe i need to import something: IndentationError: unexpected indent